# Integral doubt in distribution question.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation

[image]

Could someone please explain how in the integral in the below solution, we got $n1_{x<=1/n}$? I understand that $X_{n}$ in the question is defined as $nI_{(0,1/n]}$ and I'm aware that I is the indicator function but I'm wondering how $I_{(0,1/n]}$ became $1_{x<=1/n}$ inside the integral?

[image]

Comment: $I_{(0, 1/n]}(x)$ is zero if $0 < x \le 1/n$ and is zero otherwise.

Comment: I understand what you mean since it's an indicator function. But from what I know, the formula of E(X) is integral of x*(f(x)). So how does that formula fit here?

Comment: Note that you are given $X$ a function over the measure space $(\Omega, \mathscr{B}, \mathbf{P})$ and that $\mathbf{P}$ is already determined. Then $\mathbf{E}(X) = \int X d\mathbf{P}.$ In this case, this is a Riemann integral.

Comment: The "$U:\Omega\to\mathbb R, \omega\mapsto 1-\omega$" part here is confusing because this defines a random variable, not a probability distribution.